# convert em-dash to hyphen in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, unicode, iso-8859-1

I'm converting csv files into python Dataframe. And in the original file, one of the column has characters em-dash. I want it replaced by hyphen "-".

Partial original file from csv:

```
 NoDemande     NoUsager     Sens    IdVehicule     NoConduteur     HeureDebutTrajet    HeureArriveeSurSite    HeureEffective'
42192001801   42192002715    —        157Véh       42192000153    ...
42192000003   42192002021    +        157Véh       42192000002    ...
42192001833   42192000485    —      324My3FVéh     42192000157    ...
```

My code:

```
#coding=latin-1
import pandas as pd
import glob

pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

path = r'D:\Python27\mypfe\data_test'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None,header=0,sep=';',parse_dates=['HeureDebutTrajet','HeureArriveeSurSite','HeureEffective'],
                      dayfirst=True)
    df['Sens'].replace(u"\u2014","-",inplace=True,regex=True)
    list_.append(df)
```

And it doesn't work at all, every time it only convert them into `?`, which looks like it:

```
42191001122  42191002244    ?            181Véh   42191000114  ...
42191001293  42191001203    ?         319M9pVéh   42191000125  ...
42191000700  42191000272    ?            183Véh   42191000072  ...
```

And because I have french characters in the file, I'm using `latin-1` instead of `utf-8`. If I delete the first line and write like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None,header=0,sep=';',encoding='windows-1252',parse_dates=['HeureDebutTrajet','HeureArriveeSurSite','HeureEffective'],
                          dayfirst=True)
```

The result will be:

```
42191001122  42191002244  â??           181VÃ©h   42191000114   ...
42191001293  42191001203  â??        319M9pVÃ©h   42191000125   ...
42191000700  42191000272  â??           183VÃ©h   42191000072   ...
```

How can I make all the em-dash `—` replaced by `-`?

I added the part about `repr`:

```
for line in open(file_):
    print repr(line)
```

And the result turns out:

```
'"42191002384";"42191000118";"\xe2\x80\x94";"";"42191000182";...
'"42191002464";"42191001671";"+";"";"42191000182";...
'"42191000045";"42191000176";"\xe2\x80\x94";"620M9pV\xc3\xa9h";"42191000003";...
'"42191001305";"42191000823";"\xe2\x80\x94";"310V7pV\xc3\xa9h";"42191000126";...
```

Comment: That `repr` output is iterating over the characters of the file name, not the lines in the actual file, so it's not very useful. Use `for line in open(file_)` instead for more useful results (you'll want to pick a few example lines from the output to add to the question, rather than including it all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u'\u2014'` (EM DASH) can not be encoded in latin1/iso-8859-1, so that value can not appear in a properly encoded latin1 file.

Possibly the files are encoded as windows-1252 for which `u'\u2014'` can be encoded as `'\x97'`.

Another problem is that the CSV file apparently uses whitespace as the column separator, but your code uses semicolons. You can specify whitespace as the separator using `delim_whitespace=True`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_, delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can also specify the file's encoding using the `encoding` parameter. `read_csv()` will convert the incoming data to unicode:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_, encoding='windows-1252', delim_whitespace=True)
```

In Python 2 (I think that you're using that), if you do not specify the encoding, the data remains in the original encoding, and this is probably the reason that your replacements are not working.

Once you have properly loaded the file, you can replace characters as you have been doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_, encoding='windows-1252', delim_whitespace=True)
df['Sens'].replace(u'\u2014', '-', inplace=True)
```

---

**EDIT**

Following your update where you show the `repr()` output, your file would appear to be UTF8 encoded, not latin1, and not Windows-1252. Since you are using Python 2 you need to specify the encoding when loading the CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_, sep=';', encoding='utf8')
df['Sens'].replace(u'\u2014', '-', inplace=True)
```

Because you specified an encoding, `read_csv()` will convert the incoming data to unicode, so `replace()` should now work as shown above. It should be that easy.

Comment: @ch36r5s: please note that I have had a rethink about your problem and it now seems likely that your CSV files are encoded as `windows-1252`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I corrected as you said, and it turned out:(not the same line) `42191000095  42191000448  â??  164VÃ©h   42191000008  42191000592`. The csv file I showed is the one posted by python, the orginal one is like `"42192001833";"42192000485";"—";"324My3FVéh";"42192000157"`, so I left the `sep=';'` as it was.

Comment: This still looks like an encoding issue. Which encoding did you specify for `read_csv()`? Can you post selected output from this: `for line in open('file.csv'): print repr(line)`. Show some examples of the lines that are not correct. This should help to identify the encoding.

Comment: I updated my question with output from the beginning. And the new result with `encoding='windows-1252'`

Comment: @ch36r5s: Please add the output of `repr()` as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: it's really what I got as result. The same thing you asked? I added `for line in file_:` `print repr(line)`

Comment: @ch36r5s: Almost. I asked for `line in open(file_): print repr(line)`. Note the use of `open()` to open the file for reading. Also, please just post a few of the lines that have the problem.

Comment: @ch36r5s: that's right. That's what I want to see. Your data is UTF8 encoded, not latin1, and not windows-1252. See updated answer.

Comment: I tried and the result remains the same. there is no diffrences between `window--1252` and `utf-8`. In the meantime, I don't want to lose my correct characters like `Véh`. so how should I do that?

Comment: @ch36r5s: The data that you've shown is definitely UTF8, and the code that I've shown works for me with your data. I don't know what else to advise.

Comment: yeah, problem solved. Cause I stuck to use `print repr(line)` which caused the problem. Thanks a lot~